# check if timestamp column is in date range from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, range

I have a dataframe, df_A with two columns 'amin' and 'amax', which is a set of time range.

My objective is to find whether a column in df_B lies between any of the rows of range in df_A 'amin' and 'amax' columns.

```
df_A[['amin','amax'] ]

                  amin                   amax
          0 2016-07-16 19:37:03   2016-07-17 11:16:32
          1 2016-07-04 21:15:54   2016-07-05 10:57:46
          2 2016-07-24 23:30:41   2016-07-25 15:38:02
          3 2016-07-12 03:02:38   2016-07-12 22:11:01

df_B['created_date']

      created_date
   2016-07-17 01:16:32 
   2016-07-05 10:15:54  
   2016-07-12 12:11:01


df_A['amin'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['amin'], errors='coerce')
df_A['amax'] = pd.to_datetime(df_A['amax'], errors='coerce')
df_B['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_B['created_date'],errors='coerce')

def dt2epoch(value):
   epoch = (value - pd.to_datetime(datetime(2015,12,31).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))).total_seconds()
   return epoch    

df_A['amax_epoch']=df_A['amax'].apply(dt2epoch)
df_A['amin_epoch']=df_A['amin'].apply(dt2epoch)
df_B['created_date_epoch']=df_B['created_date'].apply(dt2epoch)


def make_tuple(row):
     n= len(row)
     row = [(x,row[n - 1]) for x in row]
     return row

minMaxTuple = minMax.apply(make_tuple, axis =1)
```

Above is part of my code, I've tried below(not sure if it's necessary):

1. convert them to epoch values
2. convert df_A into a tuple.

However, df_A and df_B has a different number of rows. Also, I dont have any id column to merge them together.

```
label = []

for l in df_B['created_date_epoch']:

    if (m[0] for m in minMaxTuple) <= l <= (m[1] for m in minMaxTuple):
        label.append('1')
    else:
        label.append('0')
```

However, when I run this, the result I get for 'label' is an empty list.

Also, the label should be a column that has the same number of rows as df_A.

Ultimately, I would like to add a new 'label' column in df_A:

```
                              minMaxTuple                      label
            (2016-07-16 19:37:03, 2016-07-17 11:16:32)            1
            (2016-07-04 21:15:54, 2016-07-05 10:57:46)            1 
            (2016-07-24 23:30:41, 2016-07-25 15:38:02)            0
            (2016-07-12 03:02:38, 2016-07-12 22:11:01)            1
```

Comment: Would you ever have data that would conflict with each other? meaning you have multiple `created_date`s that would fit into another `amin`/`amax` combo?

Comment: @MattR hmm yes this might be one of the concerns also. if this happened, do you think it will be better to just label 1 and 0 to indicate? rather than storing the original data?

Comment: what kind of data is this? this may not be a `pandas` thing. it may be a general data thing. Are there any *unique* identifiers that could be used? Before we start delving into code there may be a less-painful solution

Comment: @MattR do you mean unique key? cause they are from different table hence there isnt any. df_A is the result of clustering a series of time series data and amin amax are the min and max time of that particular cluster. while df_B is the date of an event happens that I want to label df_A data.

Comment: unique key, unique identifier. Same thing in my book. So what would be the expected result if there were two possible values in `created_date`? My fear is after this question is solved, and you will need to ask another one because the scenario I'm talking about will arise

Comment: @MattR cause my goal is to label if within that time range, did any event happen in df_B. hence at the end I will use '1' and '0' to label. I might edit my question, if this is confusing.

Comment: IIUC, If that is your goal, a duplicate should not matter since you only want to signal if an event happened. Instead of needing the date, you could use a binary `[1 or 0]`? is that correct?

Comment: @MattR yes! correct! whether a duplicate, or there's another data that also falls into that range will not be a matter to me.

Comment: perfect - I think this is a much more viable option. and thank you for editing the question to accommodate this change!

Comment: @MattR thanks for raising this as well. What would be your advice to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to see if a `created_date` in df_b falls between an `amin` and `amax` would be to use boolean logic. In a row-wise calculation for each row in `df_a` you could use the following logic:

```
if sum((row['amin'] > df_b['created_date']) | (row['amax'] < df_b['created_date'])) == len(df_b)
```

In this stament I am using the logical operator `|` to check if `amin` is less than `created_date` OR if `amax` is less than `created_date`. If the statement is `True` you could conclude that a created date does not fall between the time period created by `amin` and `amax`. If none of the `created_dates` fall between the period created by `amin` and `amax`, you could then assign a value of `0` to `df_a['label']`: Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

def myfunc(row, df_b):
    if sum((row['amin'] > df_b['created_date']) | (row['amax'] < df_b['created_date'])) == len(df_b):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

a_str= """
amin,amax
2016-07-16 19:37:03,2016-07-17 11:16:32
2016-07-04 21:15:54,2016-07-05 10:57:46
2016-07-24 23:30:41,2016-07-25 15:38:02
2016-07-12 03:02:38,2016-07-12 22:11:01"""

b_str = """
created_date
2016-07-17 01:16:32 
2016-07-05 10:15:54  
2016-07-12 12:11:01"""
df_a = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a_str), sep=',')
df_b = pd.read_csv(StringIO(b_str), sep=',')

#Convert to datetime
df_a['amin'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['amin'])
df_a['amax'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['amax'])
df_b['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_b['created_date'])

df_a['label'] = df_a.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x,df_b), axis=1)
```

Which returns a column `label` in `df_a` with the expected output of:

```
                 amin                amax  label
0 2016-07-16 19:37:03 2016-07-17 11:16:32      1
1 2016-07-04 21:15:54 2016-07-05 10:57:46      1
2 2016-07-24 23:30:41 2016-07-25 15:38:02      0
3 2016-07-12 03:02:38 2016-07-12 22:11:01      1
```

Comment: hi! this works perfectly! But can I ask why have t o check if the 'sum' of the statement is '==' to the 'len(df_B)'? @dubbbdan

Comment: @jayen I chose the OR logic (`|`) since only one condition needs to be false for a `created_date` to be not within the time period created by `amin` and `amax`. A sum treats `True` as the value of 1.  So if, all elemets series are `True` (none of the dates are within the time span) it will be equal to the length of the series `created_date`.

Comment: @jayen if the logical statement returns `True`, you can conclude none of the created dates fall within the time period created by `amin` and `amax`.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @dubbbdan 's answer but maybe simpler using `any` and the `and` operator:

```
any_in_range = lambda row, iterable: any(
    [(row[0] < x) & (x < row[1]) for x in iterable])
df_A['label'] = df_A.apply(any_in_range, iterable=df_B['created_date'], axis=1)
print df_A
```

Prints:

```
                 amin                amax  label
0 2016-07-16 19:37:03 2016-07-17 11:16:32   True
1 2016-07-04 21:15:54 2016-07-05 10:57:46   True
2 2016-07-24 23:30:41 2016-07-25 15:38:02  False
3 2016-07-12 03:02:38 2016-07-12 22:11:01   True
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was tring to do using the `and` operator

Answer (score 0):

I created a list of tuple from the max and min date columns then searched for the date-timestamp inside the this list of tuples.

```
tuple_to_search = list(zip(df_A.amin,df_A.amax))

df_B['is_true']= df_B['created_date'].map(lambda k: any(filter(lambda x : x [0]<= k <=x[1],tuple_to_search ))).astype(int)
```

Comment: I created a list of tuple from the max and min date columns then searched for the date-timestamp inside the this list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which avoids a cartesian join (helpful with memory, and performance, depending on the data size):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df_B
.conditional_join(
    df_A, 
    ('created_date', 'amin', '>='), 
    ('created_date', 'amax', '<='), 
    how = 'right')
.assign(label = lambda df: df.created_date.notna().astype(int))
.drop(columns='created_date')
)
                 amin                amax  label
0 2016-07-16 19:37:03 2016-07-17 11:16:32      1
1 2016-07-04 21:15:54 2016-07-05 10:57:46      1
2 2016-07-24 23:30:41 2016-07-25 15:38:02      0
3 2016-07-12 03:02:38 2016-07-12 22:11:01      1
```