# Checking overlaps between two columns of datetime type in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with two columns that are datetime objects (`time_a` and `time_b`). I need to check on a row-by-row basis if the elements of `time_a` or `time_b` for such row, are contained within any of the other intervals defined by the other `time_a` and `time_b` rows. That's what I defined as '**overlap**', if any period of work between `time_a` or `time_b` clashes partially with other intervals regardless of the room.

The way I managed to approach this initially was to create tuples with the data of `time_a` and `time_b`, and then checking on a row-by-row basis if `time_a` or `time_b` fell within any the range of any of these tuples.

That approach seemed convoluted, so I wanted to explore the power of Pandas for such purpose. Using [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715337/check-if-timestamp-column-is-in-date-range-from-another-dataframe) as example, I tried adapting it to my problem, using a dataframe named `test_2` (columns are `date, room, time_a, time_b, personnel_number`) whilst `test_3` only has `time_a`, `time_b` columns. I wrote my partial solution like this:

```
any_in_range = lambda row, iterable: any(
    [(x > row[2]) & (x < row[3]) for x in iterable])
test_2['label_1'] = test_2.apply(any_in_range, iterable=test_3['time_case_finished'], axis=1)
test_2['label_2'] = test_2.apply(any_in_range, iterable=test_3['time_finished_cleaning'], axis=1)
test_2['isOverlap'] = np.where((test_2['label_1'] == True) | (test_2['label_2'] == True), 1, 0)
final_overlap = test_2[test_2['isOverlap'] == 1]
```

And a sample of the outcome, is described below:

```
    date    room    time_a  time_b  personnel_number    label_1 label_2 isOverlap
77  2021-09-14  3   2021-09-14 12:01:42-07:00   2021-09-14 12:12:20-07:00   1   False   False   0
80  2021-09-14  1   2021-09-14 13:15:36-07:00   2021-09-14 13:24:50-07:00   1   False   False   0
83  2021-09-14  1   2021-09-14 14:21:52-07:00   2021-09-14 14:39:37-07:00   1   True    False   1
84  2021-09-14  3   2021-09-14 14:38:58-07:00   2021-09-14 14:52:24-07:00   1   True    True    1
90  2021-09-15  4   2021-09-15 09:25:11-07:00   2021-09-15 09:53:33-07:00   1   True    True    1
91  2021-09-15  5   2021-09-15 09:28:30-07:00   2021-09-15 09:42:25-07:00   1   False   False   0
92  2021-09-15  1   2021-09-15 09:52:18-07:00   2021-09-15 10:07:25-07:00   1   True    True    1
93  2021-09-15  3   2021-09-15 10:02:05-07:00   2021-09-15 10:20:13-07:00   1   False   True    1
```

Now, notice how row 90 is marked as 1, but my code fails to find the other row in which it is supposed to be overlapping (which should be row 91, marking a 0). The overlap is not total, even if just a minute, I still want to count it in as overlap, but my code is not fulfilling the purpose for every case in my dataset.

Any help or advice is dearly appreciated.

Comment: kindly provide a sample dataframe, possibly ten rows or thereabout as a dictionary, so it is reproducible ``df.to_dict('list')``

Comment: Are 'time_a' and 'time_b' allowed to overlap if they are on the same line?

Comment: @sammywemmy hi, the original dataframe is the same as the sample outcome, but only has the first 4 columns (that is .loc[:, 0:4]), the outcome only adds information to it.

Comment: @Nev1111 hmmm, you mean, using logic conditionals for closed intervals such as '>=' or '<='? If I understood you correctly, that will mark every row as an overlap. Unless you mean something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to boil down to finding overlapping intervals, where the intervals are defined by `time_a` and `time_b`

This can be efficiently solved with the `piso` (pandas interval set operations) package, in particular the [adjacency_matrix](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.adjacency_matrix.html) method

```
import pandas as pd
import piso

ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df["time_a"], df["time_b"])
df["isOverlap"] = piso.adjacency_matrix(ii).any(axis=1).astype(int).values
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: This was so elegant and efficient, obviously my solution with the tuples was not going to be efficient, specially iterating over the entire search space for each and single row. 

Also, I didn't knew about this piso library, first time I heard of it, and now I'll research it thanks to you. Would give you more points if I could for this answer, thank you!

Comment: @Riley I have a similar task however for two overlapping instances I would like to choose the smaller start time and larger end time. Can this also be achieved using piso?

Comment: @Marc perhaps [piso.union](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.union.html) will solve your problem?

Comment: @Marc if you post it as a question then let me know