# How to find overlapping rows between two dataframes based on start and end columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes df1 and df2 of the form:

**df1**

```
start   end   text   source
1       5     abc     1  
8       10    def     1
15      20    ghi     1
25      30    xxx     1
42      45    zzz     1
```

**df2**

```
start   end   text   source
1       6     jkl     2  
7       9     mno     2
11      13    pqr     2
16      17    stu     2
18      19    vwx     2
32      37    yyy     2
40      47    rrr     2
```

I want to return the intersections of the two dataframes based on the start and end columns in following format:

**out_df**

```
start_1   end_1   start_2   end_2  text_1   text_2
1         5       1         6      abc      jkl        
8         10      7         9      def      mno
15        20      16        17     ghi      stu 
15        20      18        19     ghi      vwx
42        45      40        47     zzz      rrr
```

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: I would create lists, explode them, merge, then drop duplicates, if you have the memory to do it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas)?

Comment: @RVA92 I think that is similar, but still too different from my use case.

Answer (score 3):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df1.conditional_join(
      df2, 
      ('start', 'end', '<='), 
      ('end', 'start', '>='))

   left                 right
  start end text source start end text source
0     1   5  abc      1     1   6  jkl      2
1     8  10  def      1     7   9  mno      2
2    15  20  ghi      1    16  17  stu      2
3    15  20  ghi      1    18  19  vwx      2
4    42  45  zzz      1    40  47  rrr      2
```

In the dev version, you can rename the columns, and avoid the MultiIndex (the MultiIndex occurs because the column names are not unique):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

df1.conditional_join(
        df2, 
        ('start', 'end', '<='), 
        ('end', 'start', '>='), 
        df_columns = {'start':'start_1', 
                      'end':'end_1', 
                      'text':'text_1'},
        right_columns = {'start':'start_2', 
                         'end':'end_2', 
                         'text':'text_2'})

   start_1  end_1 text_1  start_2  end_2 text_2
0        1      5    abc        1      6    jkl
1        8     10    def        7      9    mno
2       15     20    ghi       16     17    stu
3       15     20    ghi       18     19    vwx
4       42     45    zzz       40     47    rrr
```

The idea for overlaps is the start of interval one should be less than the end of interval 2, while the end of interval two should be less than the start of interval one, that way overlap is assured. I pulled that idea from `pd.Interval.overlaps` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8b5dfa21c662dee72b6774219a601c1aeb89abeb/pandas/_libs/interval.pyx#L577)

Another option is with the [piso](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.adjacency_matrix.html) library; the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71987527/7175713) might point you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative method in vanilla/pandas?

Comment: I'm running into errors (updating pandas does not seem to help):
pyjanitor ImportError: cannot import name 'apply_if_callable' from 'pandas.core.common'

Comment: Still having the errors? Is the error when you run the code? At what point does the error occur?

Comment: it turns out its in the import statement itself. import pyjanitor

Comment: . Use import janitor

Comment: My mistake, that's what I meant and used: import janitor

Comment: odd, cos I am not getting that error. what version of pandas are you on?

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, I got a `TypeError: conditional_join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'right_columns'` after running the code. That's weird because in the repo, we can see that keyword https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor/blob/dev/janitor/functions/conditional_join.py. Do you know how to fix this, please ? And what's about the dev version ?

Comment: @abokey, column selection is in the dev version. Packages usually have a Dev version and a release version. The Dev version has the latest but has not been released yet. You have to install it iwth this :`pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git` uninstall the current version before installing. The Dev version also supports numba for more peerformance

Comment: Thank you. I did uninstall the current version I had and then run your command who successfully installed pyjanitor-0.23.1. However, jupyter still throws the same error. It looks like I still need to run some additionnal commands in Jupyter, as per the documentation https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/devguide/.

Comment: Hmmmm ... Odd ... Lemme know how it goes.  If you can, create a new, clean environment, and then install the Dev version. If all fails, you can do the column renaming before the conditional join